# Does anyone know of a faceted search solution for Drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, faceted-search

Faceted Search module is not being moved to Drupal 7.
What are my alternatives?

Comment: Having a look around it looks like http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr is a good way forward.

Answer (score 4):

The [Search API module](http://drupal.org/project/search_api) is new for Drupal 7, and allows you to choose from a variety of backends, including [Solr](http://drupal.org/project/search_api_solr), [Xapian](http://drupal.org/project/xapian), native database and others. It supports faceted search irregardless of which backend is used.

Answer (score 2):

One option is an apache solr integration http://drupal.org/project/apachesolr or a self written lucene search module.

Comment: Solr is very popular in the drupal camp for search.  ++

Answer (score 2):

I have set a faceted search up in Drupal 7 using the Search API which has a search facets module. You will also need Entity api. The facets get created as blocks.

Although this goes on to use the Solr module, which I didn't use, I found this video very useful for some pointers on how to set up a search using search api. 
http://vimeo.com/15556855

Answer (score 0):

You (who comes from search engines) can use FacetAPI module: https://www.drupal.org/project/facetapi

It's a very easy module to create faceted search in Drupal.

(http://beautiful7mind.wordpress.com/2013/03/10/step-by-step-how-to-implement-facet-search-on-data-in-drupal-7/)