# Drupal 7 drill down menu with Checkboxes - Similar to Amazons left menu

Tags: drupal, checkbox, navigation, drupal-7

I'm new to drupal, so I'm looking for any suggestions as I am learning here.

I'm working on a site where I have a taxonomy setup like so:

Top Vocabulary: 
Events

Sub Vocab that would have check boxes:
[] New Events
[] Past Events

Category of Events
[] Webinars
[] Conferences
[] Workshops

Topics of Events ()
[] Topic 1 
[] Topic 2
[] Topic 3

When you check one of the checkboxes it just narrows down what shows in the content area.

Similar to Amazon's menu here:

[image: Amazon's menu]

After I setup the taxonomy, how do I create a menu like this?

Answer (score 4):

I have found the term I am looking for here... it's called Faceted Search. There is a module for Drupal 7 here: http://drupal.org/project/facetapi

There is also a good writeup on best practices here: http://www.uxmatters.com/mt/archives/2009/09/best-practices-for-designing-faceted-search-filters.php

There is also another post here on StackOverflow: [Does anyone know of a faceted search solution for Drupal 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6161289/does-anyone-know-of-a-faceted-search-solution-for-drupal-7)

A couple good resources I have found for Drupal 7 Faceted Search:

- http://envisioninteractive.com/drupal/drupal-7-views-with-faceted-filters-without-apachesolr/
- http://php.dzone.com/videos/video-walkthrough-faceted
- http://drupal.org/project/search_api/
- http://www.webbydude.com/posts/10-drupal-faceted-search-tutorial
- http://nickveenhof.be/blog/screencast-2-creating-facets-apache-solr-drupal-7

I hope this helps someone looking for such a thing as Faceted Search.